# How to generate XML-output from Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle

A colleague wrote this query for me :

```sql
set linesize 150
set pagesize 0
SET HEADING OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
COLUMN C0 NEWLINE

select '<?XML VERSION="1.0"?>'
FROM DUAL
/
SET EMBEDDED ON

select '<row>'                                               C0
, '<field name="orgnr">'||organisatie_nr||'</field>'         C0
, '<field name="orgnaam">'||organisatie_naam_oms||'</field>' C0
, '<field name="orgwnpl">'||woonplaats_oms||'</field>'       C0
, '</row>'                                                   C0
from organisatie_eenheid
/
```

which generates:

```
<?XML VERSION="1.0"?>                                                                                                                                 
<row>                                                                                                                                                 
<field name="orgnr">910</field>                                                                                                                            
<field name="orgnaam">Dienst Regelingen</field>                                                                                                            
<field name="orgwnpl">ASSEN</field>                                                                                                                        
</row>
```

In MySQL `mysql -u -p -X 'select organisatie_nr as orgnr, organisatie_naam_oms as orgnaam, woonplaats_oms as orgwnpl from organisatie_eenheid;'` results in something like :

```
<?XML VERSION="1.0"?>
<resultset>
  <row>
  <field name="orgnr">910</field>
  <field name="orgnaam">Dienst Regelingen</field>
  <field name="orgwnpl">ASSEN</field>
</row>
</resultset>
```

I know that Oracle can also produce XML but since I never work with Oracle, I don't know the syntax.

Which Oracle query can generate the same output as MySQL?

Comment: You can see the options and syntax [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb13gen.htm). For your desired output you may want to look at [`dbms_xmlgen.get_xml`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb13gen.htm#ADXDB5047); see [this example](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb13gen.htm#i1025636).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (taken from the docs):

```
SELECT XMLSerialize(
         DOCUMENT
         SYS_XMLGEN(
           dept_t(department_id,
                  department_name,
                  d.location_id,
                  cast(MULTISET
                       (SELECT emp_t(e.employee_id, e.last_name,
                                     e.job_id, e.manager_id, e.hire_date,
                                     e.salary, e.commission_pct)
                          FROM hr.employees e
                          WHERE e.department_id = d.department_id)
                       AS emplist_t)))
         AS CLOB)
  AS deptxml
  FROM hr.departments d WHERE department_id = 10 OR department_id = 20;
```

You can read more about how to convert a query to XML from the docs:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb13gen.htm#ADXDB5041